# SQL query - Select with SUM function with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

[image]

I'm trying to make a query to list PTR_NUM who have at total PTNG_PRICE above 7000. I'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT painter.PTR_FIRSTNAME, painter.PTR_LASTNAME,
SUM(painting.PTNG_PRICE) AS 'TOTAL PAINTING COST'
FROM painter, painting
WHERE painter.PTR_NUM = painting.PTR_NUM
AND SUM(painting.PTNG_PRICE) > 7000
GROUP BY painter.PTR_NUM;
```

I'm getting a 1111 error.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT painter.PTR_FIRSTNAME, painter.PTR_LASTNAME,
SUM(painting.PTNG_PRICE) AS 'TOTAL PAINTING COST'
FROM painter, painting
WHERE painter.PTR_NUM = painting.PTR_NUM
GROUP BY painter.PTR_NUM
HAVING SUM(painting.PTNG_PRICE) > 7000;
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple I was forgetting.